# Apache Camel splitter returns string

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I am trying to split a '@' separated string and process every token through same route.

camel-context.xml:

```
<split streaming="true">
  <tokenize token="@"/>
  <to uri="validateResubmitTransactionIdProcessor"/>
</split>
```

Following is processor code snippet:

```
epublic class ValidateResubmitTransactionIdProcessor implements Processor {
public void process(Exchange exchng) throws Exception {
    Object[] args =  exchng.getIn().getBody(Object[].class);
}}
```

I get following exception:

> eCaused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.apache.camel.Exchange but has value: 11484 of type: java.lang.String on: Message: 11484. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value 11484. Exchange[Message: 11484]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value 11484]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:101)
>       at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$35.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:847)
>       Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.Exchange with value 11484
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:169)
>       at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiTypeConverter.mandatoryConvertTo(OsgiTypeConverter.java:110)
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)nter

I am not sure if I am using splitter the right way. Also, do know how can I convert java.lang.String to Exchange. This doesn't seems to be supported by camel.

Answer (score 2):

The [Splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) creates a kind of loop and your processer gets called for every token. The body of the exchange thus contains a simple String, not a list.

**UPDATE:**
See this example:

```
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start")
            .split().tokenize("@").streaming()
            .process(new MyProcessor())
            ;
        }
    });
    context.start();
    context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:start", "1@2@3");
```

Your Processor method can look like this:

```
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
}
```

This will output three lines with the digits.

Comment: I am not expecting a List but an Exchange. Since every token is sent to processor and processor's process method can accept only exchange parameter, how can i obtain same behavior as Splitter?